# manually controlling height of the horizontal line of the radix or root symbol

Tags: symbols

While using lucida fonts, I have big problems with the height of the horizontal line of the radix or root symbol.  Sometimes 
`\[ \sqrt[x^2 + x} \]` comes out allright, but for example, in  a fraction
`\[ \frac{x^2 + x}{x^2 + x} \]`, the exponents "2" stick literally to the horizontal radix line.  I tried to fix that using a vertical strut

```
$\newcommand{\S}{\rule[0pt]{0pt}{1.6 ex}}$
```

and variants of it and write

```
\[ \frac{ \sqrt{\S x^2 + x} }{ \sqrt{\S x^2 + x} } \]
```

but this does not help.  Does anyone have better ideas?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Especially with font questions it is never a bad idea to add an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that reproduces the issue and maybe even a picture of the output, so we can compare what we get with what you see.

Comment: I can't really see the issue: look at [this picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EcH7f.png).

Comment: @egreg -- op is using lucida fonts.  lucida dimensions are rather different from those of cm.

Answer (score 1):

With the Lucida Math font (for `pdflatex`), here's what I get from the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lucimatx}

\begin{document}

\[ \frac{ \sqrt{x^2 + x} }{ \sqrt{x^2 + x} } \]

\[ \frac{ \sqrt{\mathstrut x^{2} + x} }{ \sqrt{x^{\mathstrut 2} + x} } \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't find the first display particularly squashed together; the impression might be given when looking at the result at low resolution (that is, on the screen without magnification).

In the second display I suggest two (manual) methods for obtaining more room.

If I use the OpenType version, I get from

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Lucida Bright Math OT}

\begin{document}

\[ \frac{ \sqrt{x^2 + x} }{ \sqrt{x^2 + x} } \]

\end{document}
```

the following picture, which shows perhaps better spacing.

[image]

Comment: is the lucida `\mathstrut` really so enormous as it appears in the numerator of the second example?  if so, i suspect a bug in the metrics.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Possibly so. I'm just the messenger. `;-)`